# Sorting array of array Integer where the elements to sort are int in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting

I have these two arrays of arrays of integer:

1. [[2021, 06, 24], [2021, 06, 22], [2021, 04, 19]]
2. [[2021, 04, 19], [2021, 06, 22], [2021, 06, 24]]

I want to have the same order of the two arrays, how I can do that in Java?
So I want both arrays in this order:

1. [[2021, 06, 24], [2021, 06, 22], [2021, 04, 19]]
2. [[2021, 06, 24], [2021, 06, 22], [2021, 04, 19]]

Comment: What do you mean? The same order: `list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1)`...

Comment: I'd like to have the same order of the list, if you can see the  frst element of the first list is siuated in the last element of the second list

Comment: Please identify what makes an item in the list greater than or less than or equal to others. The sub-arrays (eg [2021, 06, 24]) look like they may represent dates. Is that right?

Comment: so decreasing date order ?

Comment: @StvnBrkdll Yes they rapresent date

Comment: yes decreasing order

Comment: Could you provide the java input code ? That would be easier

Comment: I have simply defined two lists of lists and would need to sort them before comparing them

Comment: List of List of what exactly? a `List<List<String>` is different to a `List<List<Integer>` for example.  Or are you sing a raw type?

Comment: I'm using List<List<String>>

Comment: On a side note I strongly recommend you rethinking your design. If that `List<String>` represents a date you should use an explicit class for that as accidentially sorting those lists could mess up your data (think of sorting `["2021", "07", "09"]` - you'd not get the correct order here). Ideally use something like `LocalDate` or at least provide a custom class that contains the 3 string fields.

Answer (score 3):

#### Sort as date

As your date represents dates, the easier to compare them is to build date objets, using `LocalDate`.

From a `List<String> o` to `LocalDate` :

```
List<String> o = List.of("2021", "04", "19");
LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(o.get(0)), Integer.parseInt(o.get(1)), Integer.parseInt(o.get(2)))
```

Then apply this logic with `List.sort`

```
List<List<String>> values = Arrays.asList(List.of("2021", "04", "19"),
        List.of("2021", "06", "22"), List.of("2021", "06", "24"));

values.sort((o1, o2) -> LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(o2.get(0)), Integer.parseInt(o2.get(1)), Integer.parseInt(o2.get(2)))
        .compareTo(LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(o1.get(0)), Integer.parseInt(o1.get(1)), Integer.parseInt(o1.get(2)))));

System.out.println(values); // [[2021, 06, 24], [2021, 06, 22], [2021, 04, 19]]
```

---

You can extract the parser into a method and use `Comparator.comparing`

```
class DateSorter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<String>> values = Arrays.asList(List.of("2021", "04", "19"),
                List.of("2021", "06", "22"), List.of("2021", "06", "24"));
        values.sort(Comparator.comparing(DateSorter::toDate, Comparator.reverseOrder()));

        System.out.println(values); // [[2021, 06, 24], [2021, 06, 22], [2021, 04, 19]]
    }

    static LocalDate toDate(List<String> o) {
        return LocalDate.of(Integer.parseInt(o.get(0)), Integer.parseInt(o.get(1)), Integer.parseInt(o.get(2)));
    }
}
```

---

#### Sort as string

You can also just sort each list a string, in case you have strings as doubled digits like `04` and not `4`

```
List<List<String>> values = Arrays.asList(List.of("2021", "04", "19"),
        List.of("2021", "06", "22"), List.of("2021", "06", "24"));
values.sort(Comparator.comparing(List::toString, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
System.out.println(values); // [[2021, 06, 24], [2021, 06, 22], [2021, 04, 19]]
```

Comment: this return a void i'd like to return a list<List<String>>

Comment: @ValerioAuricchio then just add `return values`. Keep in mind that this is just an example and making use of a `main(...)` method which has void return type. This focuses on sorting the lists, not on returning them which is something you'd have to add if you need that.

Comment: @ValerioAuricchio what do you mean ? that is the main method os yes it is void

Comment: @azro when i use the method I'm expecting to recive a list<List<String>> in this case i reciv a void why?

Comment: @ValerioAuricchio receive from where ? How do you run the code ? Don't you know the purpose of the static void main method ?

Answer (score 1):

[It is possible to sort the input list using [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-) and [`Comparator.reverseOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--) like this:

```java
List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("2021", "04", "19"),
    Arrays.asList("2021", "06", "22"),
    Arrays.asList("2021", "06", "24")
    );
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(List::toString, Comparator.reverseOrder()));

System.out.println("Reversed = " + list);
```

Output:

```
Reversed = [[2021, 06, 24], [2021, 06, 22], [2021, 04, 19]]
```

---

Another approach is to apply method [`Comparator::reversed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) chained immediately after `Comparator.comparing` like this:

```java
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(List<String>::toString).reversed());
```

---

**Update**

If a new sorted list should be retrieved from some existing list, this can be implemented using Stream API: [`Stream::sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) and [`Stream::collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) with [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) collector:

```java
List<List<String>> sortedPartitionsValues = partitionValues
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(List<String>::toString).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Wen i try to do myList::toString i recive this error "Cannot resolve method 'toString'"

Comment: @ValerioAuricchio This answer says `List::toString`, not `list::toString` or `myList::toString`.

Comment: I wrote this : List<List<String>> sortedPartitionsValues = partitionValues.sort(List::toString, Comparator.reverseOrder()); And still recive this error "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static contex"

Comment: @ValerioAuricchio, [`List::sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method is `void` and the sorting applied to the given instance of list, in your case it is `partitionValues`.

Comment: @ValerioAuricchio, you may check the update

Answer (score 0):

This appears to solve the problem:

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] ar = new int[][] {{2021, 04, 19}, {2021, 06, 22}, {2021, 06, 24}};
        List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(ar);

        System.out.println("original:");
        list.forEach(subAr -> {
            System.out.println("[" + subAr[0] + ", " + subAr[1] + ", " + subAr[2] + "]");
        });

        list.sort((lhs, rhs) -> {
            LocalDate dlhs = LocalDate.of(lhs[0], lhs[1], lhs[2]);
            LocalDate drhs = LocalDate.of(rhs[0], rhs[1], rhs[2]);
            return drhs.compareTo(dlhs);
        });
        System.out.println("sorted:");
        list.forEach(subAr -> {
            System.out.println("[" + subAr[0] + ", " + subAr[1] + ", " + subAr[2] + "]");
        });
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
original:
[2021, 4, 19]
[2021, 6, 22]
[2021, 6, 24]
sorted:
[2021, 6, 24]
[2021, 6, 22]
[2021, 4, 19]
```

Comment: Don't suggest solutions using the old date API, especially not using `Calendar`. Have a look at `LocalDate` etc. (basically the java.time api). This is way easier to use and less error-prone.

Comment: @Thomas good suggestion, i'll revise it. However Calendar is not deprecated (yet), so...

Comment: Well, Calendar probably won't get deprecated any time soon but the same is true for AWT and other parts of the JDK and even other libraries. That doesn't mean we should suggest them for new solutions though :)